# Putting Views and Controllers in a different project than the ASP.NET Core Web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to split up my ASP.NET Core 3.0 pre-release 9 MVC app into different projects. For example, I’d like to have everything related to one subdomain go into a project called `Website.SubdomainA` and the other one into `Website.SubdomainB`.

I tried to accomplish this with a Razor Class Library. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio), these should be able to contain the follwing:

> Razor views, pages, controllers, page models, Razor components, View components, and data models can be built into a Razor class library (RCL).

So I went ahead and created a 'RCL', which looks something like the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then I copied over my Controllers and Views—but, for some reason, it can't find any of the assemblies which contain the base classes like `Controller`, `RouteAttribute` and all the others which are included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace.

Further, my Views do not compile since they can't find the needed assemblies, and things like `Layout = "Test"` get marked red.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I guess you are missing `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="{version}" />` in your project file. Or other reference needed.

Comment: @dropoutcoder Well yes, but I want the latest pre-release, see [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3756). And if I add what the link shows I get the following error: `The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' was not recognized`.

Comment: Did you tried to just install the preview package(s) from NuGet to those projects?

Comment: I am over-viewing the links and I am not sure that Framework element is yet working in the preview. It might not yet. That is why you have that error.

Comment: Well the latest `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package is version 2.2 and not some kind of pre-release

Comment: You are using preview in one project and I guess it is working. Why not just investigate the working project to find out how it is setup. Then apply what you found there to your .NET Standard projects. It is bit of trial and fail, but at this point I guess it will be only option. I doubt anyone is trying to achieve what you are trying at this stage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For creating Razor Class Library, you need to append `AddRazorSupportForMvc` in the `*.csproj` like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>`. See [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3756#issuecomment-434114175) in the issue you linked to above.

> We are removing the `netstandard2.0` from most Microsoft.AspNetCore.* assemblies.

Comment: I already tried that, but if I do this I get the following errors you can see in [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/36015290/64487053-c4e5b980-d235-11e9-8fa9-5f76ee4dff57.png) picture.

Comment: @Twenty Ok I see. Can you clear your "obj" folder contents (that will get rid of all those "*.cshtml.g.cs" errors) and see what the remaining errors are?

Comment: I cleared the `bin` as well as the `obj` folder, if I hit build, I still hit the exact same issues.

Comment: What happens if you target the web SDK instead of the Razor SDK? `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`

Comment: Well I need the Razor SDK, that is the problem... and no the errors disappear.

Comment: You shouldn't absolutely need the Razor SDK... I think the web SDK would still work for you. Also I think it may have to do with the way the new framework reference is working. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4332#issuecomment-443915806 Since MVC has moved to the shared framework (web SDK), the Razor SDK may not be aware of it

Comment: Well then it requires an entry point since it is not longer a class lib.

Comment: It should be ok without an entry point. It will just show a web app icon in VS instead of a class library icon. For example, you can use the web SDK in an integration testing project that has no entry point itself: "Specify the Web SDK in the project file (<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">). The Web SDK is required when referencing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests#test-app-prerequisites You just won't be able to run it

Comment: Well I need the reference to `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` and with the SDK set to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` the project won't build with the following error: `Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`

Comment: I don' t think you need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` reference, just the web SDK.